# Validating group of checkboxes in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just wondering how I can validate a group of checkboxes in angular, so that when none of them are selected and when they are $dirty, an error message is shown.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but $dirty does not get set for them - the last one has to be selected to have $dirty set. I'd like $dirty to get set when one of the checkboxes in the group have been touched. I've written a custom ng-required rule which checks whether one of the checkboxes has been checked or not.

Plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/lDYMXSZcCOjmBSMC7kHQ?p=info

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbox-icons" ng-repeat="type in serviceTypes" ng-if="newListing.isService" ng-click="print(newListing)">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{type.icon}}" ng-model="newListing.listingTypes[type.typeId]" name="inputListingType" ng-required="!oneCheckboxSelected(newListing.listingTypes)">
    <label for="{{type.icon}}">
        {{type.name}}
    </label>
</div>
<small class="help-block" ng-messages="addSpaceForm.inputListingType.$error" ng-show="addSpaceForm.inputListingType.$dirty">
    <span ng-message="required">This field is required</span>
</small>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.oneCheckboxSelected = function(arr) {
    return _.keys(_.pick(arr, _.identity)).length > 0;
};
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunker of your issue?

Comment: Hi @ZakHenry, I've created a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lDYMXSZcCOjmBSMC7kHQ

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring because you're trying to check the `$dirty` attribute of a form element that there is many of with the same `name`. This won't work as angular won't be able to bind the attribute to many elements.

Consider using http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/ which is a bower installable dependency for handling multiple checkboxes in one directive.

You should be able to use a custom function for `checklist-change="imChanged()"` to toggle your validation message block